# How to add two column values into one when creating Snowflake view

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a Snowflake view where one column is the value of two columns.

I have a table:

```
create or replace table database.schema.test_table (
  TEST_ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
  TEST_DETAILS VARIANT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TEST_ID)
);
```

I also want to create a view of this table:

```
create or replace view database.schema2.test_view(
  TEST_ID,
  OBJECT_NAME,
  OBJECT_ID_1,
  OBJECT_ID_2,
) as SELECT
    CONCAT(OBJECT_ID_1,OBJECT_ID_2) as TEST_ID,
    TEST_DETAILS:OBJECT_NAME::VARCHAR(16777216) as OBJECT_NAME,
    TEST_DETAILS:OBJECT_ID_1::NUMBER(38,9) as OBJECT_ID_1,
    TEST_DETAILS:OBJECT_ID_2::NUMBER(38,9) as OBJECT_ID_2,
FROM
    database.schema.test_table ;
```

In the view, I want **TEST_ID** in the as SELECT to be the value of **OBJECT_ID_1** AND **OBJECT_ID_2**, not the SUM of those two columns but I want them to literally look like OBJECT_ID_1-OBJECT_ID_2 in the column. So like 12345-67890 for example. I tried CONCAT but obviously it didn't work. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: try casting them as varchar first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I just moved the line to the bottom of the AS SELECT and that seemed to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but CONCAT works for me as expected:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(TEST_ID, '-', TEST_DETAILS) as COMPLETE_TEST_ID,
    TEST_ID,    
    TEST_DETAILS
FROM
    database.schema.test_table;
```

*UPDATE 2023-06-27* Here's a complete example with COALESCE() to handle NULL values:

```
WITH tmp_test(test_id, test_details, comments) AS (
  SELECT '1', '10', 'both not null' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', null, 'test_details null' UNION ALL
  SELECT null, '20', 'test_id null'
)
SELECT
    CONCAT(COALESCE(TEST_ID, 'n/a'), 
           '-', 
           COALESCE(TEST_DETAILS, 'n/a')) 
       AS COMPLETE_TEST_ID,
    TEST_ID,    
    TEST_DETAILS, 
    COMMENTS
FROM
    tmp_test;
```

Comment: Hi, yes I just tried it and it works when I move it to the end of the AS SELECT, but I have another problem - some of OBJECT_ID_2 entries are NULL and when they get concatenated with OBJECT_ID_1 that isn't NULL, it still comes back as NULL because of how Snowflake works. Do you know an alternative to CONCAT that doesn't make the return NULL if at least one value is NULL? Hope this makes sense!

Comment: You can `coalesce` each column before you concatenate it to replace nulls with an empty string or whatever you want.

Comment: I tried coalesce before but it still didn't work, would you be able to give an example just so I can compare what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance

Comment: @FrankSchmitt thanks Frank! I copied and pasted your answer and although it kept saying 'Numeric value 'n/a' is not recognized, I just did TO_VARCHAR as Andrew suggested and it worked! Thanks so much both, both the example and suggestion really helped :)